# Excel Functions - how to either have direct data input or cell value from formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to either populate a cell value from direct key input or have the cell value derived from a formula.

If the input Information!l5 is "n" I want to be able populate the cell manually.

=IF(Information!$L$5="y",E15*D15*62.4)

Please HELP!!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. That's not how Excel is supposed to be used.

The user input cell will always be a cell on its own. You'll need to keep the logic in a separate cell.